# Which one to choose, stdcall or cdecl?

Tags: delphi

I try to call from Delphi the function `_wputenv_s` located in ucrtbase.dll, I wrote it like this :

```
function _wputenv_s(varname: PChar; value_string: PChar): integer; cdecl; external 'ucrtbase.dll' delayed;
```

The problem I don't know if I must write cdecl or stdcall? It works well in both cases, so which one to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, functions exported from Microsoft's CRT implementations use the `cdecl` calling convention.